# Tensorflow: install it automatically in setup.py

Tags: python, tensorflow

In a `setup.py` file we usually put something like

```
install_requires=["numpy>=1.11.2", "scipy>=0.17.1"]
```

so that when the command `python setup.py install` is run, the dependencies are installed automatically.

However, I cannot manage to make it work with tensorflow. I tried to put `tensorflow>=1.0.1` or `tensorflow-gpu>=1.0.1` and a bunch of other combinations but I alway get the same error message:

`error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('tensorflow>=1.0.1')`

Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Note that I have no trouble installing tensorflow using `pip install tensorflow` or `pip install tensorflow-gpu`.

Comment: What happens if you omit the `>=1.0.1`? Does it work? Have you recently upgraded `pip`: `pip install --upgrade pip`? What version is installed with `pip install tensorflow` or `pip install tensorflow-gpu`?

Comment: @Dair I also tried without `>=1.0.1` and I did upgrade my pip beforehand. The version installed is `0.12`.

Comment: Also, if TF is already installed, it can be detected only if the correct version is mentioned in `install_requires`, i.e. putting `tensorflow` in `install_requires` cannot detect `tensorflow-gpu` and vice versa. Any workaround to this?

Comment: At which OS you want to achieve it?

Comment: Ubuntu. OS X, whichever

Comment: TensorFlow pip package requires pip version 9.0.1 or higher to properly download and install (because it is hosted out of a new pypa backend). Is it possible you have a pip version older than that?

Comment: I have a pip version 9.0.1 running on ubuntu. I am not able to install tensorflow from within setup.py due to same error. Any updates?

Comment: Still didn't find any solution to this problem to this date.

Comment: I just retried and now it works.

Comment: Any idea why it works now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, it works. Specifying  `install_requires=["tensorflow>=1.12"]` in `setup.py` and executing `python setup.py install` will install the required tensorflow version.

It also works with `tensorflow-gpu`.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use pip inside your setup.py?

Like this:

```
import pip

def install(packagename):
    pip.main(['install', packagename])

install('tensorflow')
```

Respectively put it into another script called by setup.